Android Fetching Data from Firebase Firestore Error
I create an app that is fetching some data from Firebase Firestore and display them on a list. While the app is starting is not fetching the data and this error occurs.
W/ConnectionTracker( 4843): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker( 4843): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lm@b240d73
W/ConnectionTracker( 4843):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1757)
W/ConnectionTracker( 4843):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1874)
W/ConnectionTracker( 4843):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:792)
W/ConnectionTracker( 4843):     at ce.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):1)
W/ConnectionTracker( 4843):     at ce.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):5)
W/ConnectionTracker( 4843):     at ln.A(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):10)
W/ConnectionTracker( 4843):     at ky.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker( 4843):     at dy.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):2)
W/ConnectionTracker( 4843):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
W/ConnectionTracker( 4843):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/ConnectionTracker( 4843):     at iw.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):15)

The strange thing is when I ⚡Hot Reload the running app data are showing as expected
Pubspec.yaml file
  firebase_core: ^3.2.0
  cloud_firestore: ^5.1.0

android/app/build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.2.0'
}


Looks like this is related to firebase init.
can you check if you are calling
await Firebase.initializeApp();
before accessing any services ?

I tried firebase init command and flutterfire configure but no luck same result. await Firebase.initializeApp(); is already there
